# Javascript hide and display id

Tags: javascript

I don't want a button I want a timer instead that counts down 5 seconds then the javascript function executes on page load

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.min.css" />
    <title>
        Test
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- I don't want a button I want a timer instead that counts down 5 seconds then the javascript function executes -->

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

    <div id="myDIV", class="myDIV">
        Initializing Hide
      </div>

      <div id="myDIVS", class="myDIVS">
        Hide Successful
      </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction(){
            var target = document.getElementById("myDIV");
            var show = document.getElementById("myDIVS");
            if(target.style.display = "none"){
                // target.style.display = "block";
                show.style.display = "block";
            }else{
                show.style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        
    </script>
</body>

<style>
    .myDIV{
        background-color: aqua;
        margin: 30px;
        padding: 50px 30px;
        /* display: none; */
    }

    .myDIVS{
        background-color: green;
        margin: 30px;
        padding: 50px 30px;
        display: none;
    }
</style>```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Instead of repeating what you want, please explain in detail what exactly it is you're  having trouble with.  What is your specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout). Just put the `onClick` code inside this, also I have corrected the `=` vs. `==` mistake.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var target = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var show = document.getElementById("myDIVS");
  if (target.style.display == "none") {
    target.style.display = "block";
    show.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    target.style.display = "none";
    show.style.display = "block";
  }
}

setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);
```

```css
.myDIV {
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  /* display: none; */
}

.myDIVS {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV" class="myDIV">
  Initializing Hide
</div>

<div id="myDIVS" class="myDIVS">
  Hide Successful
</div>

Wait for five seconds and see?
```